# Regression with big data

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I have data on two variables (y,x): 7 years of weekly data (364 weeks) for 80,000 groups. 
I need to demean the data by groups, and do a regression of y on (x plus 8 dummy variables that need to be created). There are 364*80,000*10, or about 30Million data points. I 'borrowed' an account on a server and find that the regression needs at least 144GB of memory. I don't usually have access to this server and my computer only have 24GB of ram.

Instead of inv(X'X)X'Y,  I am thinking to break up the regression into 8 parts. 
Regression 1 uses data for the first 10,000 groups. This gives X1'X1 and X1'y1
Regression 2 uses data for groups 10,001 to 20,000 and gives X2'X2, X2'y2
and so on, where X_j =x_j+ dummies for group_j.

Then my estimate would be inv(X1'X1+..X8'X8)(X1y1+ ... X8y8).

The problem is efficiently reading  the data to do this.
The data are in a csv file and not organized by groups.
I am thinking to read in the entire dataset and dump it out to an organized new csv file. Then I read 10,000*360 rows each time, and repeat 8 times.

My questions are

1. is there a more efficient way to do this regression?
2. is there a way to bypass creating a new csv file?  If I do have to create a new data file, what is the first format? (have never used pytable or h5py, and willing to consider)
3. Would scikit-learn be more efficient than sm.OLS, if I tweak LASSO to do an OLS instead of a regularized regression?

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not a definite answer, but some comments:

1. Using a matrix inverse is numerically not very stable. Standard solutions like [scipy.linalg.lstsq()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy-linalg-lstsq) use proper [matrix decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Inverting_the_matrix_of_the_normal_equations) instead off `inv(X'X)X'Y`.
2. Since the Least squares is a linear estimator, it is no problem to split your data in blocks and calculate the results step by step, which cuts down the required RAM. It is described [here](http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/Block-Wise_Weighted_Least_Square) how to split up a LQ into two blocks, which can be easily generalized to more blocks. The [Recursive least squares filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter) is based on that idea. For your data size, you should keep numeric stability in mind.
3. Pytables seems like a good idea, since it can handle data, which does not fit into memory. `numpy.save()` would be a simpler and faster alternative to CSVs.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't look like are able to use something like Spark's Linear Methods (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-least-squares-lasso-and-ridge-regression) to perform the regression on AWS or some other server, you may want to consider performing many repeated regressions over the available data (say 100 samples), each time removing the prior sample's observations from the next set of randomly selected observations until you have no more samples.

Not only will this give you an idea as to whether or not your dataset is following the law of large numbers (you can hypothesis test each sample), but cumulatively, the mean fit-line of all your samples may be more accurate than an OLS fit over the entire dataset.

One possible alternative to sm.OLS may be to use sklean.linear_model.LinearRegression() to run your regressions. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I cannot put the data on aws due to licensing agreement.I  tried a bunch of things sklearn's linear regression seems like the best alternative so far. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the matrix inverse doesn't scale well and can be numerically unstable, especially as your feature set approaches (or exceeds) the number of training examples you have.  You probably want to use gradient descent to compute your regression coefficients.  Check out page 5 of these lecture notes from Andrew Ng's machine learning class:

http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf