# numpy.linalg.lstsq keeps making kernel die

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I'm using the python NumPy library for a least-squares approximation. (numpy.linalg.lstsq) I am using really huge matrices and my kernel on my Jupiter notebook keeps dying. The "A" matrix is about 60,000 X 50,000, and the "B" matrix is 60,000X10. Is there a way to break up the matrix or is there anything else I can do in order to run this operation?

Comment: Some solutions [here](https://github.com/fastai/numerical-linear-algebra/blob/master/README.md#6-how-to-implement-linear-regressionvideo-8) might help or you can go for a gradient descent based solution.

Comment: Breaking the problem into blocks is probably the way to go. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647249/regression-with-big-data/28651439) which is related and has a lot of good links in the answers